# Qt Webengine not loading openstreetmap tiles

Tags: python, pyqt5, openstreetmap, qtwebengine

I wrote a python test program like this to show openstreetmap:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import sys

def mainPyQt5():
    url = 'file:///./index.html'
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = QWebEngineView()
    browser.load(QUrl(url))
    browser.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) 
mainPyQt5()
```

index.html fetched by QWebEngineView simply calls openstreetmap:

```html
<title>OSM and Leaflet</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
<div id = "map" style = "width: 900px; height: 580px"></div><script src =  "http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
         // Creating map options
         var mapOptions = {
            center: [45.641174, 9.114828],
            zoom: 10
         }
         
         // Creating a map object
         var map = new L.map('map', mapOptions);
         
         // Creating a Layer object
         var layer = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
         
         // Adding layer to the map
         map.addLayer(layer);
</script>
```

If I fetch index.html with a ordinary browser the map is shown as expected but if I call the simple python program using QWebEngineView no tiles are downloaded from openstreetmap. If I replace openstreetmap with maps.stamen.com everything is fine both with a browser or the python script.

Answer (score 5):

By default QtWebEngine does not set default headers like popular browsers do. In this case the openstreetmap server needs to know the "Accept-Language" <del>to produce the maps since for example the names of the cities will depend on the language</del> to filter non-browser traffic. The solution is to implement a [`QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor.html) that adds that header:

```py
import os.path
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class Interceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        info.setHttpHeader(b"Accept-Language", b"en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,de;q=0.7")


def mainPyQt5():
    CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "index.html")
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = QWebEngineView()

    interceptor = Interceptor()
    browser.page().profile().setUrlRequestInterceptor(interceptor)

    browser.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
    browser.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainPyQt5()
```

[image]

Comment: "In this case the openstreetmap server needs to know the "Accept-Language" to produce the maps since for example the names of the cities will depend on the language". No, OSM does not set any names based on ACCEPT-LANGUAGE header, the raster tiles at osm are not capable of that. But a missing ACCEPT-LANGUAGE header may indicate a non-browser and by that the request may get blocked.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for the clear explanation and solution!

Comment: Yes I think crnm is correct about this header restriction being more about filtering out non-browser traffic. The core openstreetmap tile server has had many struggles with traffic, and so basically you shouldn't really use it for this kind of thing, or at least _"Do not hardcode any URL at tile.openstreetmap.org as doing so will limit your ability to react quickly if the service is disrupted or blocked"_  But instead check out some alternatives listed here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers

Comment: @HarryWood and cmm You are right, I have already corrected my answer.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However it breaks my code and the python kernel dies when i run it. I suspect that the usage of a webchannel might cause the problems. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: @HeinerFrüh I do not know what you mean.

Comment: @eyllanesc never mind! I figured it out. Problem for me was that the garbage collector killed of the inspector instance during runtime and in so killed the python kernel. I had to store the inspector as a variable. Also I had to use browser.page().profile().setRequestInterceptor(interceptor) instead of browser.page().profile().setUrlRequestInterceptor(interceptor). Might be that I use an older qt version...

Comment: @HeinerFrüh See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineprofile-obsolete.html#setRequestInterceptor, setRequestInterceptor is deprecated.